# How to use prototype method inside return block of a Constructor

Tags: javascript

I have a Constructor like below

```
 var Example = (function () {
   function Example(opt) {
     this.opt = opt;
     return{
        function(){ console.log(this.check()); } // Here is an Error
     }   
   }
   Example.prototype.check = function () {
     console.infor('123');
   };
   return Example;
 }) ();

 var ex = new Example({ a:1 });
```

I know that I am doing wrong but unable to figure out the way to do this. I want to use prototype method inside the object return. Please help me on this.

Comment: You're returning an object with no key? That doesn't look good... Plus the constructor will return the instance right? What are you trying to do there exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted to run `check()` when building an instance, why not call it in the constructor?

```
var Example = (function () {
  function Example(opt) {
    this.opt = opt;
    this.check(); //this gets called when instances are made
  }
  Example.prototype.check = function () {
    console.infor('123');
  };
  return Example;
}) ();

//so `ex` is an instance of the Example Constructor
//and check gets called when you build it
var ex = new Example({ a:1 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at

```
function Example(opt) {
    this.opt = opt;
    this.check()
}
Example.prototype.check = function () {
    console.info('123');
};
```